# How do I override a plugin repository POM configuration?

Tags: java, maven

My first problem which I have already fixed, was a https error one so I did this which I found on a thread:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But now, I need to find a way to do this again(?) but for JaCoCo because it is trying to find it from the same repository, this is my JaCoCo config:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco−maven−plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare−agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare−package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And it gives me an error that it cannot find it in the central repository that I had put in the first place:

> "Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco?maven?plugin:0.7.7.201606060606 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jacoco:jacoco?maven?plugin:jar:0.7.7.201606060606: Could not find artifact org.jacoco:jacoco?maven?plugin:pom:0.7.7.201606060606 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]"

How can I fix this? also, I have apache 3.6.3 why does this https problem exist?

```
mvn -X error log:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------        ------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.044 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-19 T 11:08:29Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format..(omitted)
Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException

It appears to also give this error regardless of JaCoCo configs, although I can run the program still.
```

Comment: What was the https error which you already fixed? And can you share the complete error log?

Comment: The error was a known one in which it is only allowed download from https secure urls/websites, so It couldn't download the plugins

Comment: Then it should allow downloading of jacoco also, can you update the question with complete error log? You can also run maven in debug mode by using `-X` flag and share log.

Comment: The jacoco plugin is in MavenCentral. So you don't need another repository. First guess: From the question marks in your error message, one might come to the conclusion that the `-` in your `jacoco-maven-plugin` are not real dashes, but something else. Try to enter them again manually. Second guess: You still have a network isssue, like firewall or proxy.

Comment: I have updated the error log

Comment: The error message is probably because I have copy pasted from netbeans IDE and it cannot represent / i'll try it though

Comment: "No goals have been specified for this build" Without a valid phase you cannot build. What exactly have you called?

Comment: They actually weren't real "-" I think, or at least it works now, I'm not sure why mvn -X gives that error though